# Given a key value string values, how to encode a key and not the content (Python 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.5, encode

Given a key: value (name="My name is Bill"), in Python 3, I am trying to encode the key (that's name). Standard approaches like name.encode etc end up encoding the content. Need to encode it to bytes as next step

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to encode a variable name.  First of all, why?  Second, if you did manage to encode a variable name you would just end-up with a different variable name - you would not change an existing one.  You talk about changing a key, but a key is not a variable name, and is immutable by definiton.

Comment: This variable (key) holds a value and this goes into a tensor. A construct in tensor uses the key and the value which have the same name. Now, the key has to be encoded to bytes, else there is a incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import codecs

def encoder(obj, scheme, orig_scheme):
    # A function which will perform encoding and return encoded object
    temp_obj = {}
    for k in obj:
        new_key = codecs.encode(bytes(k, orig_scheme), scheme).strip().decode(orig_scheme)
        temp_obj[new_key] = obj[k]
    return temp_obj

dict_usr_obj = {
    "name": "Usr X",
    "age": 23,
    "gender": "Male"
}
encoded_obj = encoder(dict_usr_obj, "base64", "utf-8")
print (encoded_obj)
```